# How to get a datetime value from an Indonesian string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to import some data obtained from an Indonesian file, part of which is a date in the form '01OKT2011'. I need to be able to automatically convert these to a T-SQL datetime, eg 10-01-2011 00:00:00.

The simplest way I can think of to do it is to create a lookup table with a column for the foreign short name and one for the month number, but this is made more difficult by the fact that the only source file I have at the moment only covers October and November, and I'm not entirely sure how the other months will be abbreviated.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Does one of the built in languages in SQL Server use the same month short names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your `syslanguages` table to learn whether your SQL Server installation supports Indonesian.

Supposing that SQL Server supports Indonesian, set your language to it.  Also, `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`.  Then use the datetimes directly.

If Indonesian is not supported/installed, you should try hard to solve localization outside of the database (which I'd actually recommend even if the database server is willing to understand your month names, but I'm saving that advice for a quite different question).

In that case the following approach might help you, if not for actual use, at least for conversion of your data.

```
DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    SUBSTRING(x, 6, 4), 
    REPLACE(...(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x, 3, 3), 'JAN', 'Jan')...,'OKT', 'Oct'),...,'DEC', 'Dec')...),
    SUBSTRING(x, 1, 2)
)
```

Comment: Indonesian isn't supported. I should havementioned that I already checked that.

Comment: Also, due to reasons outside my control I have to work with the data I'm given and it has to be within the database. I was going to go with CASE and STUFF rather than the long string of REPLACEs for readability but it looks like this is the logic I'll have to use. You've confirmed that it's the worst case scenario but at least I don't have to waste any more time looking for a smarter solution.

Comment: @Jaloopa - Yes, sorry for the bad news.  Older SQL Server versions had support for "defining a language" but it's long gone.  I agree that CASE+STUFF will look much better than REPLACEs.  If you absolutely need to do these conversions in multiple places in the database, you can define a user function, a slow one, but maintainable.